# C# Null Exception using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#

I have a function where I am trying to get some text from this webpage:

http://www.nla.gd/winning-numbers/

```
public static string get_webpage(string url)
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    string date = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
    string lotto_winning_numbers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id=\"main\"]/div/strong/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]").ToString();

    return lotto_winning_numbers;
}
```

When I run the function I get a NULL Exception.

Is my xpath correct?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: No, your xpath is not correct.

Comment: Additionally, you are calling `ToString()` on a collection. So the output will be the type name of the collection, not any of the contents.

Comment: Note: using any variation of "getting NullRef exception" as title is almost automatic duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. Please avoid such titles in the future.

Comment: Please show me the error in the xpath or somewhere to learn xpath?

Comment: I am trying to capture 2,3,9,24,29 from that page but my code comes up null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256060(v=vs.110).aspx) by itself in XPath (like `[@id='main']`). You need to apply filter to collection of nodes like `div` or `*`.

Note that you also want to combine values elements in resulting collection, not convert collection itself to string.

Something like:

```
// Note "*" in front of filter
var lotto_winning_numbers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
       "//*[@id=\"main\"]/div/strong/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]");

// lotto_winning_numbers is collection of nodes here.
return lotto_winning_numbers == null ? String.Empty : 
       String.Join(", ", lotto_winning_numbers);
```

Check MSDN article [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) or many other tutorials to learn more.

Comment: Please give me a little more detail cause I am not seeing the error.

Comment: @Dami1 what details you are looking for? Like the one in the sample "Note "*" in front of condition"?

Comment: Should I remove it is there somewhere I can get the syntax for xpath?

Comment: I see you meant Not but you wrote note.

Comment: @Dami1 - I've updated answer with more correct term ("filter" instead of "condition") so you should be able to find articles about filtering in XPath (also [condition in XPath](http://www.bing.com/search?q=condition+in+XPath) is reasonable search term too).

Comment: It's not retrieving the data?